# Python - get specific text from string variable

Tags: python

I have a `str` in Python.

```
str = "*> 103.5.126.0/24     192.168.1.1          0    200      0 58424 ?"
```

What I want is to get some text from this string and put in variables
as below:

```
prefix = "103.5.126.0/24"    
nexthob = "192.168.1.1"    
metric = "0"              
LP = "200"
```

Comment: Can you explain what you want more? On what basis do you want to split up the string? What code have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

Just split it and assign the relevant portion:

```
prefix, nexthob, metric, LP = s.split()[1:5]
```

I changed the variable name to `s`, as `str` is already a Python type you shouldn't shadow.

Comment: Literally just about to post this.

Comment: @Malik Shows how obvious this is :-)

Comment: Well, +1 for the *obvious* answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
s = "*> 103.5.126.0/24 192.168.1.1 0 200 0 58424 ?"
lst = s.split()
prefix = lst[1]
nexthob = lst[2]
metric = lst[3]
LP = lst[4]
print "Prefix =", prefix
print "Nexthob =", nexthob
print "Metric =", metric
print "LP =", LP
```

prints

```
Prefix = 103.5.126.0/24
Nexthob = 192.168.1.1
Metric = 0
LP = 200
```

Comment: Or you can eliminate `lst` using: `_, prefix, nexthob, metric, LP, _, _, _ = s.split()`

Comment: @boardrider while you are correct, the code in this answer shows clearly what is happening (i.e. that split() returns a list and which element of that list will have what value).